# What's the easiest way to turn a list data structure into string in Elixir

Tags: elixir

Noobie question :)

How to transform a list data structure into a string in Elixir?

Examples:

```
["all"]               # into "['all']"
["project", "labels"] # into "['project', 'labels']"
```

Comment: Are you trying to convert a list to JSON? If not, how do you want to handle characters like `\n` or non printable ones like `"\u{0}"`?

Comment: Hi @Dogbert, yes, I want to convert this list to JSON format.
inspect ["a", b] solved the problem.

Do you think that this solution it's okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not claim the only right decision but maybe this will be helpful:

```
iex(13)> a = ['project', 'labels']
['project', 'labels']
iex(14)> b = inspect a
"['project', 'labels']"
```

But for double quoted srting:

```
iex(21)> c = ["all"]
["all"]
iex(22)> d = inspect(c) |> String.replace("\"", "'")
"['all']"
```

Because `"all"` is a binary, but `'all'` is a char_list. From [here](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html)

Comment: one should be careful with a list of numbers with this approach. For example, `inspect [7, 8]` converts the list to `"'\\a\\b'"` (i.e. the list is interpreted as a list of char codes, see the [official guide](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html#char-lists)). To get the list as `"[7, 8]"` use an option `charlists: :as_lists` like this: `inspect [7, 8], charlists: :as_lists`. (saw this solution in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40324929/list-printed-as-string-in-elixir/40324994#40324994))