# Integer List printed as String in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I was trying my hand on `Enum.map`. I found this weird output, when I added 100 to all the elements of the list.

[image: Terminal Screenshot]

Why such an output? It turns out that I am getting a string when I add 100 but works just fine when I do other operation. I fiddled some more, I still got unexpected results like this.

[image: Terminal Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**The value you see `'efgh'` is not a String but a [Charlist](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html#char-lists).**

The result of your statement should be  `[101, 102, 103, 104]` (and it actually is), but it doesn't output it that way. The four values in your list map to `e`, `f`, `g` and `h` in ASCII, so `iex` just prints their `codepoints` instead of the list. If the list contains invalid characters (such as 0, or 433 like in your case), it leaves it as a simple list.

From Elixir's [Getting Started guide](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html#char-lists):

> A char list contains the code points of the characters between single-quotes (note that by default IEx will only output code points if any of the chars is outside the ASCII range).

Note that in *Elixir 1.6+* and above, you might see the result as `~c"efgh"`, which is the new default way of printing charlists.

---

So `'efgh'`, `~c"efgh"` and `[101, 102, 103, 104]` are all equal in Elixir, and to prove that you can force `inspect` to print them as a List instead:

```elixir
[101, 102, 103, 104] == 'efgh'
#=> true

[101, 102, 103, 104] == ~c"efgh"
#=> true

[101, 102, 103, 104] |> inspect(charlists: :as_lists)
#=> [101, 102, 103, 104]
```

---

**You can also configure IEx to always print charlists as lists:**

```elixir
IEx.configure(inspect: [charlists: :as_lists])
```

You can either call the above manually in a running IEx session or add it to an [`.iex.exs`](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/1.14/IEx.html#module-the-iex-exs-file) file to ensure it is always applied in one of the following ways:

- **Current Project:** Add it to a file called `.iex.exs` in the same directory as your `mix.exs` file
- **All Projects:** Add to an `.iex.exs` file in your home folder (i.e located at `~/.iex.exs`.)

Comment: Wow! Thanks for this smooth answer. I had ignored this part while posting this question. 

Thanks again!

Comment: You can also configure IEx (through the `~/.iex.exs`) to *always* inspect the charlists as lists of integers, with `IEx.configure inspect: [charlists: :as_lists]`

Comment: how do you configure the global charlist in testing?