# how can i remove escape characters while using Enum.chunk_every with a list of integers

Tags: enums, elixir

if I use this on a list of strings , I don't get any escape characters but with list of integers i do get escape characters.

```
 Enum.chunk_every([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],2)
//output
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], '\a\b', '\t\n']
```

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40324929/integer-list-printed-as-string-in-elixir - pipe the outpu through inspect `|> inspect(charlists: :as_lists)`

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff to use it globally, edit `~/.iex.exs` to include `IEx.configure(inspect: [charlists: :as_lists])`. To use it on per project basis, do this in `.iex.exs` on the top level of the mix project directory.