# FunctionClauseError when passing :discard to Enum.chunk_every

Tags: elixir

So i have been doing a udemy course  to learn Elixir, where i am suppose to take list and create new list  that contains a lists of values in length of 3

So this is my old list

`[23, 137, 4, 86, 54, 223, 37, 191, 22, 167, 25, 238, 102, 56, 39, 4]`

and i want to convert it to this

`[[23, 137, 4],[ 86, 54, 223],[ 37, 191, 22],[ 167, 25, 238],[ 102, 56, 39]]`

My code

```
  def main(name) do
    name
    |> hash
    |> pickColor
    |> buildGrid
  end

  def buildGrid(%Identicon.Image{hex: hex}=image) do
    hex
    |>Enum.chunk_every(3, :discard)
  end

  def pickColor(%Identicon.Image{hex: [r,g,b | _tail]} = image) do
     %Identicon.Image{image | color: {r,g,b}}
  end

  def hash(name) do
    hex = :crypto.hash(:md5,name)
    |> :binary.bin_to_list()
    %Identicon.Image{hex: hex}
  end
```

the response im getting is

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Enum.chunk_every/4

    The following arguments were given to Enum.chunk_every/4:

        # 1
        [23, 137, 4, 86, 54, 223, 37, 191, 22, 167, 25, 238, 102, 56, 39, 4]

        # 2
        3

        # 3
        :discard

        # 4
        []

    Attempted function clauses (showing 1 out of 1):

        def chunk_every(enumerable, count, step, leftover) when is_integer(count) and count > 0 and is_integer(step) and step > 0

    (elixir 1.15.0) lib/enum.ex:547: Enum.chunk_every/4
    (identicon 0.1.0) lib/identicon.ex:23: Identicon.buildGrid/1
    iex:6: (file)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing this:

```elixir
iex> Enum.chunk_every(list, 3, :discard)
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Enum.chunk_every/4
```

But you need to do this:

```elixir
iex> Enum.chunk_every(list, 3, 3, :discard)
[[23, 137, 4], [86, 54, 223], [37, 191, 22], [167, 25, 238], [102, 56, 39]]
```

---

There are actually three forms of [`Enum.chunk_every`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#chunk_every/2):

1. Two-argument form: [`Enum.chunk_every/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#chunk_every/2), is a shortcut to the three argument argument form: `chunk_every(list, count)` → `chunk_every(list, count, count)`, where the `count` is also passed as the third argument, `step`.
2. Three-argument form: [`Enum.chunk_every/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#chunk_every/4), is actually the four-argument form where the default value of the fourth argument, `leftover`, is the empty list: `chunk_every(list, count, step)` → `chunk_every(list, count, step, [])`. This differs from the two-argument form, because `step` is not optional.
3. The four-argument form, same as the three-argument form but with an explicit value for `leftover`.

Your code is doing `Enum.chunk_every(enum, 3, :discard)`, attempting to pass `:discard` as the fourth `leftover` argument, but without passing the required third `step` argument. So Elixir is correctly complaining that there is no version of this function that takes `(list, integer, atom)` arguments. The fix is to pass the required third argument `step`, with the same value as `count`.

It's confusing, because the two-argument version allows the `step` to default to `count` automatically (and by extension, `leftover` to default to `[]` automatically), but the four-argument version requires that you pass `step` explicitly, while still allowing the `leftover` argument to be optional.

Comment: then i stumble upon another error, When i in sert ` iex> Enum.chunk_every(list, 3, 3, :discard)`  the return value is different from what im expecting. ` [[23, 137, 4], [86, 54, 223], [37, 191, 22], [167, 25, 238], ~c"f8'"] ` what happend to my last chunk?

Comment: Nothing happened to your last chunk. `'f8\'' == [102, 56, 39] #⇒ true`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40324929/integer-list-printed-as-string-in-elixir for further explanation.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, Thank you for the link, much appriciated!